# How to overwrite bulk clone function for laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, clone, bulk, laravel-backpack

I am trying to overwrite a bulk clone function.
I just want to clone some values, and the rest assign a static value. For example, I just want to clone the name and description values, and the date I want to assign it the current date.
And well I don't know how to do it.

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\BulkCloneOperation { bulkClone as traitBulkClone; }

public function bulkClone($id) {
    // your custom code here
    $this->traitBulkClone($id);
}
```

Comment: Can you share any code you have ? What is this method you are trying to _overwrite_ ?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: **The most efficient way would probably be to overwrite the `replicate()` method on your model.** Note that it is not a Backpack method, but an Eloquent method that `BulkCloneOperation` uses to duplicate a particular entry.

WHY?

[Inside the `BulkCloneOperation`](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Http/Controllers/Operations/BulkCloneOperation.php) that you're using, you'll notice the route calls the `bulkClone()` method, that itself is just making some calls to the `replicate()` method on the model. That means you have two options to override this behaviour:

(Option A). Override the `bulkClone()` method in your CrudController. This will override the behaviour only on that particular admin operation.

(Option B). Override the `replicate()` method in you Model. That way, any time `replicate()` is called (by your admin panel or any other part of your software), the duplication is done in the way you specified.

---

In most cases, I think Option B is more appropriate, since it would avoid future code duplication. Here's Laravel's `replicate()` method at this time, just copy-pasting it into your model and modifying it to fit your needs is the best solution, if you ask me:

```php
    /**
     * Clone the model into a new, non-existing instance.
     *
     * @param  array|null  $except
     * @return static
     */
    public function replicate(array $except = null)
    {
        $defaults = [
            $this->getKeyName(),
            $this->getCreatedAtColumn(),
            $this->getUpdatedAtColumn(),
        ];

        $attributes = Arr::except(
            $this->getAttributes(), $except ? array_unique(array_merge($except, $defaults)) : $defaults
        );

        return tap(new static, function ($instance) use ($attributes) {
            $instance->setRawAttributes($attributes);

            $instance->setRelations($this->relations);

            $instance->fireModelEvent('replicating', false);
        });
    }
```